# Redirect to url with some addition in the url

Tags: javascript, redirect, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Suppose, i've my current url:

```
http://localhost:3000/contests
```

after the button press, i am going to redirect to the following url:

```
http://localhost:3000/contests?keywords=algo
```

My problem is, i want to redirect to the path with other additional information like:

```
http://localhost:3000/contests?keywords=algo&show=present
```

here, the **&show=present** is added to the redirected url. How can i do that using javascript?

**How can i get the redirect url using javascript?**

Comment: Show some code, so people can get a better picture of what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your button click.

```
    var url=document.URL + "&show=present";
    window.location.href = url;
```

Use `document.URL` to get the current url.

Hope this will help you!!

Answer (score -1):

```
location.href = location.href + "?keywords=algo"
```

also check all the other possibilities with `window.location` object [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location)

Comment: I need the redirect url, location.href only gives the current url.